# How to select a date range without using a from table clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a basic sql query where it outputs all dates between 3-15 months from current date:

```
DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE()) AND (DATEADD(month, 15, GETDATE()))
```

The catch is though there is no table to select from. I just want to perform a basic SELECT to get the list of dates. Is this possible?

Comment: Date range here is a set. I don't think `SELECT` can output a set without table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will help you to pull all dates between two dates.

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '2015-05-28'
SET @Date2 = '2015-06-30'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there already is an accepted answer, I propose an alternative that doesn't depend on undocumented and unsupported system tables.

```
declare @Date1 date = '2015-05-28';
declare @Date2 date = '2015-06-30';
declare @Dates table (Date Date);

while @Date1 <= @Date2
begin
  insert into @Dates (Date) values (@Date1);
  set @Date1 = DateAdd(Day, 1, @Date1);
end

select * from @Dates;
```